# Highrise API is returning a 404 error

Tags: node.js, api, highrise

I am working on a web app that uses Highrise to store customer info, the app uses node.js and I'm using an npm package to hit highrise's api. When I try to hit the api to add a customer it is sending a request to the correct path (/people.xml) according to the highrise docs but it always returns a 404 error, what could be the problem here?

Comment: Please read the following article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible problem could be the wrong credentials (token and account) that you use.

You can find the token in Settings > My Info > API Token and the account in your subdomain, for example if you have the this subdomain: http://subdomain.highrisehq.com, the account is **subdomain**.

For more details take a look [HERE](https://help.highrisehq.com/users/api-token/)

Comment: Sorry, I had previously solved this and forgot to add it as an answer, this was the issue.  I was using an npm package to make the highrise call and was using the username I used to sign in as `username` somewhere in the code, but it turned out I needed to use the username that highrise generally uses in the api endpoints which is usually your first and last name with no spaces.